# Which version of Ubuntu will work out of the box on Intel 82845G Board?

Tags: intel-graphics

I am new to Linux. I have tried tried many Linux distro but none of them work on motherboard with Intel 82845g/gl graphics card. The only version that worked out of the box was Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS. None of the latest release works on my dreaded PC.

How can I install i810 driver in 12.04?

Ubuntu developers please support old computers. What should I do with this old PC?

Comment: The GPU you mention is obsolete and will not be able to run Ubuntu 12.04 smoothly, if it runs at all. From my experience, the driver causes X lockups, and while a patched version exists, it has serious stability issues.

Ubuntu 12.04 is not designed for graphics card from 2005, it relies heavily on OpenGL. Consider trying out Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the hardware you use falls into the category of "abandoned by the vendor". i8xx chips have been causing xserver lockups for years, with Intel unable or unwilling to provide fixes. There is a good overview of the predicament in the [i8xx unsupported wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/i8xxUnsupported). I wish there had been a solution, but it is highly unlikely that anyone will ever bother fixing it. As far as I know, none of the modern desktop distos will work with Intel's i810. You could try using it as a server with no X, or get a supported PCI graphics card.

There seems to be a vicious pattern with some of Intel's hardware. First, it works reasonably well, then, as the Linux kernel evolves, and regressions creep in, things start breaking, and Intel guys either completely ignore the problems, or disable the features that caused them (like hardware acceleration).

Answer (score 0):

All last versions of Xubuntu works as fast as the famous WindowsXP does this. During last years I live daily on Xubuntu with 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE.