# Ubuntu 12.04 with Intel 82845g/gl graphics card

Tags: 12.04, drivers, intel

I have an old machine with the intel card in the title installed.
I'd really need to install Ubuntu 12.04 on it, but that's not just possible since the intel drivers don't work properly. So no video acceleration, no window decorations, and lots of other issues.

I do know it's an obsolete unsupported card (see [Which version of Ubuntu will work out of the box on Intel 82845G Board?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185079/which-version-of-ubuntu-will-work-out-of-the-box-on-intel-82845g-board)) but I think I read somewhere that there had been progress as of late with the latest intel drivers.

My question is: is there anything I can currently do to make this card work or should I just give up on the idea and turn to lighter DE like LXDE or XFCE?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this thread is pretty much dead, but I found some information that may help any future visitors who come here as I did in a desperate search for answers. I have a circa-2004 Dell Dimension 2400 I really wanted to install Linux on for a client, and was about to give up - esp. after reading numerous posts like this - when I decided to give Lubuntu 14.04 a try. Much to my amazement it installed and ran fine with all updates installed. Its not the perfect DE for this particular client (I was hoping for something a little more Windows-like, as they are Linux virgins) but hey, it works! Hope this info helps someone else as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things

1. 82845G Boards are around 10 years Old.
2. Ubuntu 11.04 on-wards Unity is there as default GUI.

Now Unity requirement is different as mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

And installation requirement for ubuntu is mention [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

So I think your system is not meeting minimum requirement for Ubuntu. As a test u can try live disk too, will be batter.

Or you need to try some Older Ubuntu versions Like 10.10 or 10.04

May be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For what it was worth I was running Ubuntu 14 on an old Dell Dimension 2400 with intel 845G x 86/MMX/SSEL 3D extreme graphics agp and it was slow as molasses.  It would take 10 seconds to render a basic window open.

I have now switched to Lubuntu and the system is performing great.  And I am able to play video (like YouTube) which was causing me grief before.

So I would say switching to the lighter UI really makes a world of difference.